# Displaying divs inside container in dynamic number of rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display divs in rows. User chooses number of divs and then I want to display them in rows which number depends on number of divs. For example if user picked 6 I want to have 2 rows with 3 divs, if he picked 12 I want 3 rows with 4 divs etc

Here is what I have:
jquery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
$('#container').html('');
var k=$('select').val();
for(var i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    $('#container').append('<div class="square"></div>');
}
});
```

CSS:

```
#container{
border-style: solid;
float:left;
}
.square{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<button>OK</button>
<div id='container'></div>
```

Jfillde: https://jsfiddle.net/nrh1tzd1/

How can I order those divs in rows?

EDIT:

I figured out I could just add < br> when I want to end row. But I have one question about it. I have code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function(){
$('#container').html('');
var k=$('select').val();
 contained_divs = '';
 for(var i=0;i<k;i++)
 {
    contained_divs += '<div class="square"></div>';
    if(i!=0 && i%2==0)
    {
        contained_divs += '<br>';
    }   

}
$('#container').append(contained_divs);
}); 
});
```

Here is updated jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrh1tzd1/2/

And it works, it ends row after displaying 3 divs. But I don't understand how it works exactly.

Inside if I have

```
i%2==0
```

so it starts new row after 3 divs, but why doesnt it start third row after displaying 2 divs in second row. Variable i is equal to 4 then so it should. Also when inside that if I would use just

```
i==2
```

then it doesn't work like i want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the append function in concatenation way like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $('#container').html('');
    var k=$('select').val();
    var contained_divs = '';
    for(var i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        contained_divs += '<div class="square"></div>';

    }
    $('#container').append(contained_divs);
});
```

Updated JSFiddle Version: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrh1tzd1/1/)